# populating a structured array throws "ndarray is not C-contiguous" error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, structured-array

I am working with a structured array defined in this way:

```
scores = np.empty((num_of_imgs, 4),
                               dtype=[('id', 'u4'), ('bestT', 'u8'), ('bestR', 'f8'), ('bestP', 'f8')])
```

then in a for loop I populate it:

```
scores[i] = [id, bestT, bestR, bestP]
```

where all the vars inside the list are numpy arrays with shape (1,).
However this line of code throws the aforementioned error. Why?

Comment: Have you tried "scores[i,:] = [id, bestT, bestR, bestP]"?

Comment: The error still persists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `scores` assignment is making a nx4 array of 4-tuples, which is an extra dimension bigger than you want, I think.  It should be

   ```
   scores = np.empty(num_of_imgs,
       dtype=[('id', 'u4'), ('bestT', 'u8'), ('bestR', 'f8'), ('bestP', 'f8')])
   ```
2. Then you're trying to assign a list to a tuple, which is throwing your c-contiguous error (numpy isn't as helpful at converting types for structured arrays as it is for ndarrays).  Make the assignment a tuple. (using `()` instead of `[]`)

   ```
   scores[i] = (id, bestT, bestR, bestP)
   ```